# Converting the row output to column in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to learning Hive.

I have a table of only 1 column (string type) having output as say

```
> select * from table1;
a
b
c

d
e
f
```

I want to write a hive query in such a fashion that my desire output should be like:

```
abc def
```

can someone please suggest.

Comment: Is your desired output 2 columns?

Comment: No it is single column..

Comment: Although I have found a work around, first collecting the values with collect_list(), then changing the list column to string, and then using translate() replace '\002' with ''